# mule : Transactions in Batch Processing

Tags: mule

I have JMS inbound endpoint which subscribes to the topic. once there is a message transformer splits the payload into list of records and then insert into database using batch-commit. If there is any error while inserting into the database I want roll back the entire payload to JMS. How to achieve this using transactions?

```
<batch:job name="lockboxBatch" max-failed-records="-1">
        <batch:input>
            <jms:inbound-endpoint topic="lockbox" connector-ref="Active_MQ1" doc:name="JMS">
            </jms:inbound-endpoint>
            <custom-transformer class="transformers.PaymentsTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload[2].batchAmount='hghghfghfhgf']]></expression-component>
                <batch:commit size="4" doc:name="Batch Commit">
                    <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database" bulkMode="true" >
                        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO TIB_INT_AR_PAYMENT_IFACE (TRANSMISSION_REQUEST_ID,DESTINATION_ACCOUNT,ORIGINATION,TRANSMISSION_RECORD_COUNT,TRANSMISSION_AMOUNT,LOCKBOX_NUMBER,LOCKBOX_BATCH_COUNT,LOCKBOX_RECORD_COUNT,LOCKBOX_AMOUNT,BATCH_NAME,BATCH_AMOUNT,BATCH_RECORD_COUNT,ITEM_NUMBER,CURRENCY_CODE,REMITTANCE_AMOUNT,TRANSIT_ROUTING_NUMBER,ACCOUNT,CHECK_NUMBER,CUSTOMER_NUMBER,OVERFLOW_INDICATOR,OVERFLOW_SEQUENCE,INVOICE1,AMOUNT_APPLIED1) VALUES (#[payload.?transmissiosnRequestID],#[payload.?destinastionAccount],#[payload.?origination],#[payload.?transmissionSrecordCount],#[payload.?transmisssionAmount],#[payload.lockboxNumber],#[payload.lockboxBatchCount],#[payload.lockboxRecordCount],#[payload.lockboxAmount],#[payload.batchName],#[payload.batchAmount],#[payload.batchRecordCount],#[payload.itemNumber],#[payload.currencyCode],#[payload.remittanceAmount],#[payload.transitRoutingNumber],#[payload.account],#[payload.checkNumber],#[payload.customerNumber],#[payload.overflowIndicator],#[payload.overflowSequence],#[payload.invoice1],#[payload.amountApplied1])]]></db:parameterized-query>
                    </db:insert>
                </batch:commit>
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step1" accept-policy="ONLY_FAILURES">
             <set-payload value="#[getStepExceptions()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <foreach collection="#[payload.values()]" doc:name="For Each">
                    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="Invalid_Transmission" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
                </foreach>
            </batch:step>


        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete>
            <logger message="Completed the insert" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things.

1.Make **max-failed-records="0"**,this will rollback in case of any failure in batch step.

2.Encomapss the DB connector inside transaction scope,and handle the exception scenario as required.

```
 <transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
    <db:insert...>........</db:insert>
 </transactional>
```

Please consider below updated code,you can make changes to suit your requirements.

```
<batch:job name="lockboxBatch" max-failed-records="0">
    <batch:input>
        <jms:inbound-endpoint topic="lockbox" connector-ref="Active_MQ1" doc:name="JMS">
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        <custom-transformer class="transformers.PaymentsTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </batch:input>
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
            <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload[2].batchAmount='hghghfghfhgf']]></expression-component>
            <batch:commit size="4" doc:name="Batch Commit">
                    <transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
                        <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
                            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO TIB_INT_AR_PAYMENT_IFACE (TRANSMISSION_REQUEST_ID,DESTINATION_ACCOUNT,ORIGINATION,TRANSMISSION_RECORD_COUNT,TRANSMISSION_AMOUNT,LOCKBOX_NUMBER,LOCKBOX_BATCH_COUNT,LOCKBOX_RECORD_COUNT,LOCKBOX_AMOUNT,BATCH_NAME,BATCH_AMOUNT,BATCH_RECORD_COUNT,ITEM_NUMBER,CURRENCY_CODE,REMITTANCE_AMOUNT,TRANSIT_ROUTING_NUMBER,ACCOUNT,CHECK_NUMBER,CUSTOMER_NUMBER,OVERFLOW_INDICATOR,OVERFLOW_SEQUENCE,INVOICE1,AMOUNT_APPLIED1) VALUES (#[payload.?transmissiosnRequestID],#[payload.?destinastionAccount],#[payload.?origination],#[payload.?transmissionSrecordCount],#[payload.?transmisssionAmount],#[payload.lockboxNumber],#[payload.lockboxBatchCount],#[payload.lockboxRecordCount],#[payload.lockboxAmount],#[payload.batchName],#[payload.batchAmount],#[payload.batchRecordCount],#[payload.itemNumber],#[payload.currencyCode],#[payload.remittanceAmount],#[payload.transitRoutingNumber],#[payload.account],#[payload.checkNumber],#[payload.customerNumber],#[payload.overflowIndicator],#[payload.overflowSequence],#[payload.invoice1],#[payload.amountApplied1])]]></db:parameterized-query>
                        </db:insert>
                    </transactional>

            </batch:commit>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step name="Batch_Step1" accept-policy="ONLY_FAILURES">
         <set-payload value="#[getStepExceptions()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            <foreach collection="#[payload.values()]" doc:name="For Each">
                <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="Invalid_Transmission" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
            </foreach>
        </batch:step>


    </batch:process-records>
    <batch:on-complete>
        <logger message="Completed the insert" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I put db connector inside transactional scope and if there is a failure will it try to rollback and retry(send it to inbound JMS again ) or it will just rollback and send it as a failure record to next step.